# Application of Morera's Theorem to show that a function is analytic

Tags: complex-analysis

I believe that this exercise can be resolve using Morera's Thm. I multiplied the expression by the denominator function of $f$ but it did not help.

Could anybody help me on this one?

Let $D$ a connected open set. Assume that $f$ is the quotient of two analytic functions on $D$. Show that if $a_{0}(z) + a_{1}(z)f(z) + a_{2}(z)(f(z))^{2}+ ... +  a_{n-1}(z)(f(z))^{n-1}+(f(z))^{n}=0$ for some analytic functions $a_{0}(z),a_{1}(z),a_{2}(z),... ,  a_{n-1}(z)$ then f is analytic.

Comment: Maybe i am missing a point here, but what would be an example of a function that is the quotient of analytic functions and is not itself analytic?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: A rational function?

Answer (score 0):

Let $f=\frac g h$ with g and h analytic. We may suppose that g is not a constant so its zeros are isolated. We may also assume that p and q have no common zeros. Let $h(c)=0$ and let $N$ be the order of the zero. Multiply the given equation by $(z-c)^{Nn}$. Letting $z \to c$ we find that $g(c)=0$. This contradicts our assumption that g and h have no common zeros. We have proved that h cannot have any zeros after all so f is analytic.

Comment: Nice explanation. I believe that when you wrote p and q you really mean $g$ and $h$. Thank you for your time @Kavi Rama Murthy

Comment: Sorry, I should have said g and h have no common zeros.